# Many JS files included, one breaks all, smart approach to fix?

Tags: plugins, files

I'm doing a project that uses svg-edit(JS drawing tool) and the page grows big. By now there are about 20 JS file in a page - plug-ins and so on.

One of the editor's files breaks in some kind of 'Uncaught TypeError' but it's compressed and can not understand anything.

I used several jquery plug-ins that are important for the usability of the page and it's not possible to remove any of them. There are severe conflicts obviously but I can't rewrite any of the plug-ins.

Any smart approach to fix this ? Where I can start ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual approach is to run with uncompressed files in development environment, and with compressed files in production environment.

This way, the development environment lets you find out where the error is, in a clear code. While the production environment benefits from compressing the files.

Of course, it means being able to run a development environment. You can, right?

Comment: I can run it, but not sure whether I'd be able to change any crucial code in the editor or any of the plug-ins

Comment: @Borislav: There are two relevant scenarios here. 1) You're making a mistake and the library's error reporting isn't being helpful, but sane source could be. 2) The library has a bug, in which case what else do you expect to do about it? You'd at least know, and depending on licensing you might be able to submit a patch.